# How to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} c^n\sqrt n = 0$, where $c\in(0,1)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> How to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} c^n\sqrt n = 0$, where $c\in(0,1)$?

We often claim that exponent is "stronger" than root (and we even proved it last semester) but I can't remember how.

Comment: basically $(1+(\frac{1}{c}-1))^n \ge 1+n(\frac{1}{c}-1)$ as long as $c \in (0,1)$ (Bernoulli's Inequality) so ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$c^n\sqrt n=e^{n\ln c}\sqrt n=e^{n\ln c+\ln\sqrt n}$ but

$n\ln c+\ln\sqrt n=n(\ln c+\dfrac{\ln \sqrt n}{n})\to -\infty$ ((because $\dfrac{\ln \sqrt n}{n}\to 0$ and $\ln c<0$)). Hence $c^n\sqrt n\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write $a=\frac{1}{c}$. Then $a>1$. Let $a=1+x$. Using $(1+x)^n>nx$ and the Squeeze Theorem, you can get easily the limit.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence is positive, so

$$\sqrt[n]{c^n\sqrt n}=c\sqrt{\sqrt[n]n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}c<1$$

and by the $\;n$- th root test the infinite series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c^n\sqrt n\;\;\;\text{converges}\;\;\implies c^n\sqrt n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $c^n\sqrt{n} \leq c^nn$.Next you can use l'Hospital rule, let $f(x)=\frac{x}{c^{-x}}$, then:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{c^{-x}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{-c^{-x}\ln(c)}=0$$